# create react app not working Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

create react app is not working recently and I get this error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Node couldn't find your project's modules. Have you tried

`npm i`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).